# Proof of inequality containing a function and its integral

Tags: analysis, inequality

I came across a proof that used following equalty, but for me it didn't look that obvious and I was not able to prove it, can you give me a hint (is it even true)? The statement of the inequality was following:

Let $T>0$, $u: [0,T] \to \mathbb R$ continuous, $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, $\beta \geq 0$ such that $$ u(t) \leq \alpha + \beta \int_0^t u(s) ds \quad \forall t \in [0,T].$$

Then $$ u(t) \leq \alpha e^{\beta t} \quad \forall t \in [0,T].$$

Comment: Key name: [Gronwall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check it. If I am wrong give me the reasons.

Let $T>0$, $u: [0,T] \to \mathbb R$ continuous, $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, $\beta \geq 0$ such that $$ u(t) \leq \alpha + \beta \int_0^t u(s) ds \quad \forall t \in [0,T].$$

Then
$$ u'(t) \leq  \beta  u(t)  \quad \forall t \in [0,T].$$ 
i.e $u(t) \leq ae^{\beta t}$.

So is $a$ necessarily be $\alpha$

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't expect it to be so simple=)

Comment: $u$ is not assumed to be differentiable.

Comment: $f(t)\le g(t) $ does not imply $f'(t) \le g'(t)$.

Comment: Yeah but two same funtions are on the both side 1 is in the integral form. Then it does.